# Ground turkey raw in crockpot

Tags: turkey, crockpot, ground

I forgot to cook turkey first. How long should I cook ground turkey on high in crockpot?  It’s one pound of ground turkey already defrosted in spaghetti sauce.  It’s already in it.  It’s the original crockpot from 1980
Thank you 
Karen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My slow cooker manual gives, for 500-800g (1-1.5lbs) of poultry 3.5-4 hours on high.  However I find this one a little fierce, so I looked in an older recipe book.  Recipes for similar amounts of poultry with sauce also come to 3.5-4 hours on high, but assume you brown the meat first (but nowhere near fully cook). This book says to add 1-2 hours if you don't pre-brown the meat.  It also assumes that you preheated the crockpot, if not add half an hour. On that basis I get to 5-6 hours assuming you preheated it, which fits with what I recall from when I used to cook this sort of thing in the slow cooker.